# Is it possible to get all audios in audio library and store into a MPMediaItemCollection without using mediapicker

Tags: iphone

I hope to sue codes to load all audios into a MPMediaItemCollection object without using mediapicker manual action.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by doing a MPMediaQuery, here is a [posting](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2601469&tstart=75)

here is the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)